# Loading Viewbag data list from Json Result

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, viewbag

In my application, from the view I assigned a combo box to select the supplier from the list. And then the selected ID I'm sending to the JasonResult and there I did this,

```
public JsonResult AutocompleteSupplierFromName(int SupplierID) 
{
  var Supplier = db.Suppliers.Where(x => x.ID == SupplierID).ToList();
 
  if (Supplier.Count() == 0) {
    return Json(new {
      Success = false
    });

  } else {
    ViewBag.Item_ID = new SelectList(db.Items.Where(x => x.Status == true && x.Supplier_Id == SupplierID), "ID", "ItemName_Number");

    return Json(new {
      Success = true, supName = Supplier.ToList().First().Supplier_Name, supID = Supplier.ToList().First().ID, supAddress01 = Supplier.ToList().First().Supplier_Address_Line01, supAddress02 = Supplier.ToList().First().Supplier_Address_Line02, supContact = Supplier.ToList().First().ContactNumber
    });
  }

}
```

I want to know, from this Can I load the `ViewBag.Item_ID` to the view bag ??

Because when I checked the `ViewBag.Item_ID` from the view, It returns null.

This is the full code

```
var dropdownOptions;

try {
  $.ajax({
    url: rootDir + 'Ajax/AutocompleteSupplierFromName',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    data: {
      SupplierID: supID
    },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.Success == true) {
        document.getElementById('AddressLine01').value = data.supAddress01;
        document.getElementById('AddressLine02').value = data.supAddress02;
        document.getElementById('ContactNumber').value = data.supContact;
        document.getElementById('Supplier_Name').value = data.supName;
        $(".SupplierIDClass").val(data.supID);
        dropdownOptions = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Item_ID));
        console.log(dropdownOptions);
      } else {
        alert(data.userName);
      }
    }
  });

} catch (e) {

}
```

Edited

I changed the jsonresult to

```
 public JsonResult AutocompleteSupplierFromName(int SupplierID) 
 {
   var Supplier = db.Suppliers.Where(x => x.ID == SupplierID).ToList();

   if (Supplier.Count() == 0) {
     return Json(new {
       Success = false
     });

   } else {
     DropDownJasonData data = new DropDownJasonData();

     data.Results = GetSupplierItem(SupplierID);

     data.Pagination = new Pagination {
       More = true
     };

     string JSONresult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.Results);

     return Json(new {
       Success = true,
         items = JSONresult,
         supName = Supplier.ToList().First().Supplier_Name,
         supID = Supplier.ToList().First().ID,
         supAddress01 = Supplier.ToList().First().Supplier_Address_Line01,
         supAddress02 = Supplier.ToList().First().Supplier_Address_Line02,
         supContact = Supplier.ToList().First().ContactNumber

     }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }

 }

 private List < Result > GetSupplierItem(int SupID) 
 {
   List < SelectListItem > Items = (from i in db.Items where i.Supplier_Id == SupID && i.Status == true select new SelectListItem {
     Text = i.ItemName_Number, Value = i.ID.ToString()
   }).ToList();

   List < Result > dataList = new List < Result > ();

   if (Items.Count != 0) {
     foreach(var record in Items) {
       dataList.Add(new Result {
         Text = record.Text, Id = int.Parse(record.Value)
       });
     }
   }
   return dataList;

 }
```

So then I'm trying to put the data into the dropdownOptions. Here is my try and I got an error here. Can someone correct me here.?

```
function getSupDt(supID) {

        try {
            $.ajax({
                url: rootDir + 'Ajax/AutocompleteSupplierFromName',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                data: { SupplierID: supID },
                success: function (data) {
                     
                    if (data.Success == true) {
                        document.getElementById('AddressLine01').value = data.supAddress01;
                        document.getElementById('AddressLine02').value = data.supAddress02;
                        document.getElementById('ContactNumber').value = data.supContact;
                        document.getElementById('Supplier_Name').value = data.supName;
                        $(".SupplierIDClass").val(data.supID);
                        console.log(data.items);
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.items; i++) {
                            dropdownOptions = [
                                {
                                    value: data.items[i].id,
                                    text: data.items[i].text
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        console.log(dropdownOptions);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(data.userName);
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (e) {

        }

    }
```

Comment: `ViewBag` doesn't exist in your case, because you're not returning a razor-generated *view*.  Include all the data you need in the JSON result.

Comment: *when I checked the ViewBag.Item_ID from the view* - the `ViewBag.Item_ID` you "checked" was generated when the page was rendered (razor-generated) - ie when the page was first loaded.  Server-side variables (`@variable`) do not change once the page has been sent to the client.

Comment: *I got an error* - what's the error?

Comment: @freedomn-m Hi! After your instructions, I tried to pass the data list from the javascript and then load the data to the ``dropdownoptions`` could you check that? I have updated my question

Comment: @freedomn-m here ``console.log(dropdownOptions);`` returns Undefined . I think data not properly passed to it from the ``for`` loop

Comment: nvm: `items = JSONresult` -> you're assigning a JSON (ie a string) to `items` then doing `for (var i = 0; i < data.items; i++) {` in the js - at this point, data.items is a *string*.  Only convert to JSON once. ie, in the c# `items = data.Results,`  *or*  `JSON.parse(items)` in the js.